# Python : Extract substring if exist from another string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a value if exist from an url using regex ,

My string :

```
string = "utm_source=google&utm_campaign=replay&utm_medium=display&ctm_account=4&ctm_country=fr&ctm_bu=b2c&ctm_adchannel=im&esl-k=gdn|nd|c427558773026|m|k|pwww.ldpeople.com|t|dm|a100313514420|g9711440090"
```

From this string, I want to extract : c427558773026 , the value to extract will start always by c and have this pattern |c*|

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('|c\w|')
pattern.findall(string)
```

The result is none in my case, I am using python 2.7

Comment: Try `(?<=\|)c\d+(?=\|)` https://regex101.com/r/f4SqNX/1

Answer (score 2):

You could assert a pipe (not that it is escaped) `\|` on the left and right using lookarounds, and match a `c` char followed by 1+ digits `\d+`

```
(?<=\|)c\d+(?=\|)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4SqNX/1/)

```
import re
string = "utm_source=google&utm_campaign=replay&utm_medium=display&ctm_account=4&ctm_country=fr&ctm_bu=b2c&ctm_adchannel=im&esl-k=gdn|nd|c427558773026|m|k|pwww.ldpeople.com|t|dm|a100313514420|g9711440090"
print(re.findall(r"(?<=\|)c\d+(?=\|)", string))
```

Or use a capturing group leaving out the lookbehind as @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) suggest:

```
\|(c\d+)(?=\|)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BadoZt/1)

Comment: You do not need lookarounds with `re.findall` where the matches are not overlapping. `re.findall(r'\|(c\d+)\|', text)` will be faster.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right about that. Not that it is in the example data, but it will match a single time in `|c427558773026|c427558773026|` if that can occur.

Comment: Great, then, this is a case of overlapping matches and you can use `r'\|(c\d+)(?=\|)'`, no need for an unanchored lookbehind.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice, thanks! That is why you are the master :-)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your approach is that `|` is the *or*, which must be escaped to match the literal character. Additionally, you could use look-ahead/look-behind to ensure that `|` is encapsulating the string, and not capture it with `findall`

Here is a code snippet that should solve the problem:

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = "utm_source=google&...&esl-k=gdn|nd|c427558773026|m|k|..."
>>> pattern = re.compile('(?<=\|)c\d+(?=\|)')
>>> pattern.findall(string)
['c427558773026']
```

Comment: It is a reposted [The Fourth Bird's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262662/3832970) 8 mintes after the original answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew When I wrote my answer, his answer was incomplete and lacked the complete code solution.

Comment: I'm feeling tender for the flak and downvote. The answer is complete, has explanations, and contains a ready-made solution.